# replace audio using FFMPEG.Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ffmpeg

I have used [FFMpegCore](https://github.com/rosenbjerg/FFMpegCore) which is wrapper library for using ffmpeg in .net Core.
It has a simple 'ReplaceAudio' method for changing audio of existing video, but it doesn't work and nothing changes in output video.

```
FFMpeg.ReplaceAudio(inputPath, inputAudioPath, outputPath);
```

does it have any trick or requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

using Mute function before using ReplaceAudio will fix the problem.

```
FFMpeg.Mute(videoFile, mutedVideo);
FFMpeg.ReplaceAudio(mutedVideo, audioFile, videoFile, true);
```